# Variables in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would have a lot more possibilities if I could add variables to my commands. Is there anyway to do this?

I have tried to use armor stands but it requires a command block for every single possibility.

Comment: Use scoreboards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since JSON does not directly allow the use of variables, you could create scoreboard objectives using `/scoreboard objectives add objname dummy displayname` to add the objective, `/scoreboard players add playername objname num` to add scores, and `/scoreboard setdisplay location objname` to set where the objective is displayed, which is optional.